# Scripting and Storing Google Form Responses to a database

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've created a Google Form called "Career Progress Report Form" which stores the type of activity you've done on the day. I've created this to keep track of contacts, events, tasks, interviews, etc.

[Career Progress Report Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1q4U7hi9EE-JQRE3H0x65fo4orVdrvBm23SfMrGtvK1Q/viewform)

The Google Form was easy to create and the types of activities separate into different individual pages, however when it sends the responses to a spreadsheet it combines all results. The spreadsheet has too many columns  and not well organized. My ultimate goal is to store the records into a database where I could refer back to contacts, create individual reports on certain activities, create leads, opportunities, and accounts, and other career oriented tasks. I was considering creating individual spreadsheets for each type of activity so I would be able to create those exact columns as tables to a database.

How can this be done?

Details (updated frequently)

So for instance, stay I want to input today that participated in a webinar on Data Analytics and write a note that the webinar was in BrightTalk. On the response spreadsheet, it would input a new record:

| Timestamp | Date | Type of Activity | Type of Program | Subject/Focus | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

The .... means that there are other columns there that refer to that page. Career Development is page 3 and starts at "Type of Program". Page 2 before that is Research which associates with "Type of Media", "Subject", and "Notes"
So the problem is that the columns for the entire form are in line with each other. So If I needed to see clearly what new information I entered I would have to scroll to the side. Hope this better explains.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at their [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/):

Here is a SO question regarding reading from a Google Doc Spreadsheet: [spreadsheet api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314001/how-to-use-the-google-spreadsheets-api-to-feed-data-to-an-application)

Essentially, read the values from the spreadsheet and insert them to your DB.

Comment: @Traestar  whatever the result let us know. That way we know if that was the correct solution to your issue.

Comment: The question that you've sent to me that referred to spreadsheet api, I'm not able to use that. So right now I'm backwards engineering from a PHP perspective to accomplish a similar result to the google form (PHP form to MySQL). Sorry if you are looking for a quick response, I'm working on it as I type.

Comment: After I'm done, I will compare the results to the google form as well as look for a way to connect the form to the MySQL database potentially