# Accessing CSV from a Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: csv, d3.js, google-sheets, hotlinking

I try to access a Google Docs Spreadsheet, so I can use it in a D3.js visualization.
Both

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s04t-0r5dtY4c31czCGCaxRS_nbAMDmoUJ5O75leGPE/export?format=csv&id (as in [Accessing google docs spreadsheet revisited in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819484/accessing-google-docs-spreadsheet-revisited-in-2014))
- http://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=1s04t-0r5dtY4c31czCGCaxRS_nbAMDmoUJ5O75leGPE&exportFormat=csv&gid=0 (as in [Using the google drive API to download a spreadsheet in csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619805/using-the-google-drive-api-to-download-a-spreadsheet-in-csv-format))

do work for downloading the data, but not for using them for other websites, as I am getting an error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

However, an approach that should work ([Download unpublished Google spreadsheet as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730712/download-unpublished-google-spreadsheet-as-csv), see also [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/MN81FgPPU18as)):

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1s04t-0r5dtY4c31czCGCaxRS_nbAMDmoUJ5O75leGPE&output=csv&gid=0

does not work at all (redirect to typical edit view).

For another variant, used by http://christopheviau.com/d3list/gallery.html:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqMEGBUNwXeHdHpQNlVuY29SUE5BSXVtS3JueGlNYVE&single=true&gid=0&output=csv

I cannot do the same with my code (changing keys results in an error: `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.`).

What I am doing wrong?